# Posting a comment in new lines instead of single line in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I post a comment in asp.net as

```
Hi
How are
You
```

but after posting it comes in a single line like :

```
Hi How are You
```

i want to avoid this and show the text as the user has posted in the format:

```
Hi
How are
You
```

How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: Show some sample code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "\n" with break tag.

```
var comments = txtComments.Text.Replace("\n","<br/>");
```